# Powershell Function in function

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I want to execute the 2 functions, the first function "ad" is for executing the list from the users, then appropriate outputs  needs to be updated in the output function using csv format, while executing the script the output is empty.

```
$out = "F:\inactive.csv"

function ad () {
    $users = Get-Content "C:\dis1.txt" 
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        try {
            $memberof = Get-ADUser $user -Properties * -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object samaccountname, memberof
            foreach ($groups in $memberof) {
                if ($group=$groups.memberof -like "*mobile*") {
                    foreach ($name in $group) {
                        $gpnames += "$((Get-ADGroup $name).samaccountname);"
                        $gpname= "$($memberof.samaccountname),Exist,$($gpnames)"
                    }
                    Write-Output $gpname
                } else {
                    Write-Output "$($memberof.samaccountname),Exist"
                }
            }
        } catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
            $usrname = "$($user),NotExist"
            Write-Output $usrname
        }
    }
}

function output {
    param($usrname,$memberof,$gpnames,$ad)
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        UserAccount = $memberof.samaccountname
        NotExist = $usrname
        GroupNames = $gpnames
    }

    $gpnames = $memberof = $usrname = $null
    output | Select-Object useraccount, notexist, groupnames | Export-Csv $out
} return output
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking. What difficulty do you meet ?

Comment: Two Functions needs to execute , one for extraction and other one is for output in csv format.

Comment: What is the error? What is the behavior you are trying to correct?

Comment: output file is generated as                                                                          #TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"UserAccount","NotExist","GroupNames"
,,

Comment: That still doesn't explain what isn't working as expected. Do you want the `#TYPE ...` line removed from the output CSV? If so, add the parameter `-NoType` to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - sorry for the inconvenience , the function output contains only empty spaces apart from the 2 lines  #TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject "UserAccount","NotExist","GroupNames" , i want to write a program using 2 functions , one  is for processing the list and other is for output

Comment: Please don't bury relevant information in comments. [Edit] your question where it can be formatted properly.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - updated the questionnaire accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is misguided. Have your function `ad` return a list of objects, then pipe those objects into `Export-Csv` to create a CSV output file:

```
function ad {
  Get-Content 'C:\dis1.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Properties samaccountname, memberof
    if ($user) {
      $user | Select-Object SamAccountName,
        @{n='UserExists';e={$true}},
        @{n='Groups';e={
          ($_.MemberOf |
            Where-Object { $_ -like "*mobile*" } |
            Get-ADGroup |
            Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName) -join ','
        }}
    } else {
      New-Object -Type PSObject -Property {
        SamAccountName = $_
        UserExists     = $false
        Groups         = $null
      }
    }
  }
}

ad | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If you absolutely must have a separate function for the output (for whatever unknown reason) wrap `Export-Csv` in a function like this:

```
function output($filename) {
  $Input | Export-Csv $filename -NoType
}
```

and connect the two functions with a pipe:

```
ad | output 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Ansgar Wiechers.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiecher - Done , Thanks a lot for your help, its works as excepted. Just started learning of PowerShell scripts, thinking of exporting the files in csv format using different ways. 
I’ve a query about the $input variable, what is this all about.

Comment: [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/3.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiecher - thanks again, could you please provide me a good article about powershell scripting , which must have in & out of scripting.